# Mostrar texto predeterminado en un input sin que pueda borrarlo

Tags: php, javascript, html

El problema es que lo que yo escribo en el *input* `email` me lo muestra en el *input* `email1` el texto escrito junto con las palabras **@dominio.com**. Quisiera que el **@dominio.com** me lo mostrara directamente al *input* `email`.

Intenté con un método pero hace que al escribir una letra me cree siempre el **@dominio.com**.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#email").keyup(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $("#email1").val(value + '@dominio.com');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No se puede editar la parte donde indica **@dominio.com** pero lo que yo quiero es que se sobreponga ese dominio y siempre se pueda escribir delante de él en el primer campo, el `email`, y en caso tal de que intenten borrar aunque sea el mínimo este se restablesca a como estaba antes.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#email").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("#email1").val(value + '@dominio.com');
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="email" id="email"
  placeholder="Unicamente debes colocar tu nombre del correo">

<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="email1" id="email1" readonly="">
```

Comment: Bienvenido a _StackOverflow_. ¿Esto es una respuesta o una pregunta? No se entiende muy bien la pregunta. ¿Qué significa **escribir delante**? En la pantalla no existe _delante_, el único _delante_ que hay es tú estando _delante_ de la pantalla. Yo cambiaría el término por izquierda o derecha.

Answer (score 0):

por lo que entiendo te refieres a hacer algo como esto http://jsfiddle.net/h677zt4f/3/

En tu caso, podrías hacer lo siguiente con tu código:

```
$("#staticEmail").on('keyup', function(){
    var str = $(this).val();
    var suffix = "@dominio.com";

    if(str.search(suffix) === -1){
        str += suffix;
    }

    var actualLength = str.length - suffix.length;

    $(this)
        // set the value
        .val(str.substr(0,actualLength) + suffix)
        // set cursor position
        .get(0).setSelectionRange(actualLength,actualLength);    
});
```

y en HTML quedaría algo así:

```
<input type="text" id="staticEmail" placeholder="@dominio.com"/>
```

Comment: No entiendo porque el codigo no me lo toma, literal copie y pegue en una prueba y no me funciono

Comment: Ok ahora vi porque no me funcionaba pero hay un problema, mi idea es que no puedan escribir despues del @ dominio .com y que no puedan borrar esos datos, porque que pasa, si yo borro si acaso el .com o solo la m este me vuelve a crear los mismos datos

Comment: Muy bien si ves el codigo, claro si intentas moverte con las direcciones del teclado este te manda al inicio, pero si vas a darle click directamente al final y escribes alguna otra letra este te devuelve al inicio pero el error esta en que devuelve con el @, es decir, si escribes algo despues de alli como hola este te lo devuelve al inicio diciendo @ hola y si borras cualquiera cosa del dominio pues pasa como con el hola te devuelve los datos al inicio pero te escribe todo de nuevo

Comment: Por ejemplo si borras la m del dominio.com te devuelve al inicio diciendo @ dominio.co@ dominio.com y etc con cualquier letra si llegaras a borrar la m de dominio te deja @ doinio.com@ dominio.com